# Function Dir in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, directory, vba

Does anyone know how is the order in which the VBA function `Dir` returns filenames determined? The function work as follows (description from [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php)):

> The Microsoft Excel DIR function returns the first filename that matches the *pathname* and *attributes* specified. To retrieve additional filenames that match *pathname* and *attributes*, call DIR again with no arguments.

So let's say I apply `Dir` to some folder `path` with files x, y and z. Suppose that `Dir(path)` returns z, then calling `Dir` twice returns y and x respectively.

**How was the order z-y-x determined?**

---

**EDIT: some context**

My question is motivated by the following fact: when I applied `Dir` to this folder `path` with files x, y and z it returned the filenames in a given order. Then, for some reason I took out these files from the folder, put them again in `path` and applied `Dir` again; the order had changed.

Comment: There is AFAIK no *dependable* sort order.  If you need a specific order then you'll have to sort the output.